# Book about a female with animal tattoos that can move around on her body

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

- I think I read this book in the mid to late 2000s.
- The main character is female with tattoos that can move around on her body.
- She can even take them off and they become small figurines until she puts them back on.
- I think at one point she is running from someone in woods and/or snow when they hit her with some type of magic; it knocks her out and causes all her tattoos to fall off her body.
- I can’t remember if the tattoos give her special abilities, are more like spirit animals, or even familiars.
- I remember one tattoo is a black panther that at one point swats at someone when they get too close, and another tattoo is of a lizard that hides behind her eyebrow.

Comment: Duplicate? [https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/novel-about-a-tattoo-that-comes-to-life-and-jumps-off-the-persons-body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/novel-about-a-tattoo-that-comes-to-life-and-jumps-off-the-persons-body)

Comment: This isn’t any of those. The tattoos can’t live off of the FMC’s body. They are just figurines then.

Comment: Good to know. I assumed you meant that they could move once they were off her body too, might be worth an edit to clarify.